# Termination of ssh with Ctrl-C trap in bash script

Tags: bash, signals, trap

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> with the first script, it works as I expect, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> doesn't have any effect

```
#!/bin/bash
trap '' INT
ssh user@server 'svn checkout ...'
echo "done"
```

But with the second script <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> somehow terminate SSHconnection and proceed with next part of the script

```
#!/bin/bash
trap 'echo "message"' INT
ssh user@server 'svn checkout ...'
echo "done"
```

I thought in the second script <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> should only print "message" into console, without termination SSH connection. Why is this happening? Is it possible print some message each time <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is pressed, without terminating `ssh`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `''` in `trap '' <signame>` is special. It will cause `<signame>` to be *ignored*, not bound to dummy handler.

The "ignore" disposition of a signal is inherited by child processes (e.g. by ssh), but signal handlers are not.

`trap '' INT` is not the same as `trap true INT` or `trap ' ' INT`.

`help trap` in bash would've told you as much:

> If `ARG` is the **null string** each `SIGNAL_SPEC` is **ignored** by the shell and by the commands it invokes.

---

It's hard to tell what you really want to do, but if you just want your script to print a message when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, without the `ssh` command being terminated, this will do:

```
#!/bin/bash
trap 'echo "message"' INT
ssh user@server 'svn checkout ...' &
while :; do
        wait
        s=$?
        case $s in
        130)    ;;
        129|13?) kill -n "$((s - 128))" "$$";;
        *)      exit "$s";;
        esac
done
echo "done"
```

Change `ssh ... &` to `(trap - QUIT; trap '' INT; exec ssh ...) &` if you want to still be able to kill your script via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>\</kbd> (`SIGQUIT`).